# What's the simplest way to get string between specific two characters?

Tags: java, regex

For example, I have front boundary 'x'  and back boundary 'y'

E.G.
Given a string 'abcxfoobaryblablah', it should return 'foobar'.

Assume the two boundaries only appear exactly once in the string like in the example.

Thanks! Doesn't have to use Regex, but I guess that's the best method.

Comment: idk java but the regex is `x([^y]+)`. You could also do `x(.*?)y`. If it really is once then `x(.*)y`. You can use substr and search for the index of x, y then substr between it. No regex required there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
String s = "abcxfoobaryblablah";
s = s.substring(s.indexOf('x') + 1, s.indexOf('y'));
System.out.println(s);
```

Out

```
foobar
```

Comment: Yes, but you will get problems if either 'x' or 'y' is missing, or if 'y' appears before 'x'.  In this case, unchecked exceptions ...

Comment: True but he can tailor it to his specific need, I don't know what other requirements he might have.

Answer (score 0):

Check out java's boundary matchers http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html

Answer (score 0):

May be a long code but just a simple logic.

```
String str="abcxfoobaryblablah";
char array[]=str.toCharArray();
boolean flag=false;
String answer="";

for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
if(array[i]=='x'){
    flag=true;
    continue;
}
if(array[i]=='y') break;
if(flag)answer+=array[i];
}

System.out.println(answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String  input = "abcxfoobaryblablah";

int startIndex = input.indexOf("x");

int endIndex =  input.indexOf("y");     



String output = input.substring(startIndex+1, endIndex);

System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly do substrings, but it is possible with regex.

```
String str = "abcxfoobaryblablah";
str = str.replaceAll("^.*x|y.*$", "");
```

`^.*x` matches the characters from the start of the `String` up to `x`. `y.*$` matches the characters from `y` to the end of the `String`.

Note that if `x` is after `y`, then this will keep just the characters after `x` to the end of the `String`. If `x` is not present, it will keep the characters from the start of the `String` to `y`. If you only want it to work when **both** `x` and `y` are in there in the correct order, then this is what you want:

```
String str = "abcxfoobaryblablah";
str = str.replaceAll("^.*x(.*)y.*$", "$1");
```

This uses [groups](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is:

```
String middle = str.replaceAll(".*x(.*)y.*", "$1");
```